# How to use STRING_AGG that selects from JOINs within an outer SELECT that also has JOINs

Tags: sql-server, string-agg

I have a compound SELECT statement that retrieves its values (columns) from several Joined tables. I want to add a column to the result set that is a STRING_AGG. The values that will be used in the STRING_AGG are retrieved from joined tables, including one of the tables that are in a JOIN already. If I run the STRING_AGG statement by itself, it returns exactly what I expect. I need to be able to combine the STRING_AGG with the existing compound SELECT statement, if possible.

The standalone STRING_AGG, which outputs a string with comma delimited values as expected, is as follows:

```
DECLARE @iIbrId INTEGER
SET @iIbrId = 1189  
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),sCdmName), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sCdmName) AS CardMarks
    FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT sCdmName 
    FROM mpm_icabinreq_ibr
    INNER JOIN mpm_icabinreq_cardmark_rcm ON iRcmIbrId = @iIbrId
    INNER JOIN mpm_cardmark_cdm ON iRcmCdmId = iCdmId) x
```

My SELECT statement that I wish to add the SELECT STRING_AGG to as a column in the result is as follows:

```
DECLARE @iIbrId INTEGER
SET @iIbrId = 631
SELECT a.iIbrId AS "Request Number", iIbsStatus, 
    sPerFirstName + ' ' + sPerLastName sPerFullName, a.iIbrRequest, a.iIbrTypId, sTypName,
    a.sIbrDesc, a.dIbrTarget, a.sIbrTransfer, a.iIbrBIN AS BIN, a.sIbrBINExtStart, a.sIbrBINExtEnd, a.iIbrEntIdClient,
    b.iIbrEntIdProcessor iPreviousProcessor
    FROM mpm_icabinreq_ibr a
    INNER JOIN mpm_ibrstatus_ibs ON a.iIbrId = iIbsIbrId
    INNER JOIN mpm_person_per ON iIbsPerId = iPerId
    INNER JOIN mpm_type_typ ON iTypId = a.iIbrTypId
    LEFT JOIN mpm_entity_ent ON iEntId = a.iIbrEntIdClient
    LEFT JOIN mpm_icabinreq_ibr b ON b.iIbrId = a.iIbrParentId
    LEFT JOIN mpm_multibank_mbk ON a.iMbkEntId = mpm_multibank_mbk.iMbkEntId
    LEFT JOIN mpm_bin_bin ON a.iIbrBin = iBinId
    LEFT JOIN mpm_icabinpseudort_irt ON iIrtIbrId = a.iIbrId
```

How can I add this SELECT STRING_AGG that uses joined tables to an existing SELECT statement that also uses one or more of the joined tables?

I want to add this column to an existing SELECT statement that uses one or more of the same tables in different joins. When I do this, I get NULL in all "CardMarks" columns.

This is the SQL statement that includes the SELECT STRING_AGG but that column returns NULL under this circumstance.

```
DECLARE @iIbrId INTEGER
SET @iIbrId = 631
SELECT a.iIbrId AS "Request Number", iIbsStatus, 
    sPerFirstName + ' ' + sPerLastName sPerFullName, a.iIbrRequest, a.iIbrTypId, sTypName,
    a.sIbrDesc, a.dIbrTarget, a.sIbrTransfer, a.iIbrBIN AS BIN, a.sIbrBINExtStart, a.sIbrBINExtEnd, a.iIbrEntIdClient,
    b.iIbrEntIdProcessor iPreviousProcessor,

    (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),sCdmName), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sCdmName)  AS CardMarks
    FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT sCdmName 
    FROM mpm_icabinreq_ibr
    INNER JOIN mpm_icabinreq_cardmark_rcm ON iRcmIbrId = @iIbrId
    INNER JOIN mpm_cardmark_cdm ON iRcmCdmId = iCdmId)x)

    FROM mpm_icabinreq_ibr a
    INNER JOIN mpm_ibrstatus_ibs ON a.iIbrId = iIbsIbrId
    INNER JOIN mpm_person_per ON iIbsPerId = iPerId
    INNER JOIN mpm_type_typ ON iTypId = a.iIbrTypId
    LEFT JOIN mpm_entity_ent ON iEntId = a.iIbrEntIdClient
    LEFT JOIN mpm_icabinreq_ibr b ON b.iIbrId = a.iIbrParentId
    LEFT JOIN mpm_multibank_mbk ON a.iMbkEntId = mpm_multibank_mbk.iMbkEntId
    LEFT JOIN mpm_bin_bin ON a.iIbrBin = iBinId
    LEFT JOIN mpm_icabinpseudort_irt ON iIrtIbrId = a.iIbrId
```

Comment: You have not provided the actual query you are asking about so it's not clear at all what answer you're expecting. Please have a read of [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then edit your question.

Comment: Added much more detail, with the full query with and without the SELECT STRING_AGG

Comment: I really suggest getting into the habit of using aliases, and when you do using ***good*** aliases. `a` for `mpm_icabinreq_ibr` and `b` is for `mpm_icabinreq_ibr` really don't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the naming convention for your table structure, `mpm_icabinreq_cardmark_rcm` is a junction table that defines a many-to-many relationship between `mpm_icabinreq_ibr` and `mpm_cardmark_cdm`. Given an `iIbrId` corresponding to an `mpm_icabinreq_ibr` row from your main query, you want a aggregate of all `sCdmName` values contained in `mpm_cardmark_cdm`.

My first question is which copy of `mpm_cardmark_cdm` in your main query are you interested in? This will drive whether you are looking up names based on `a.iIbrId` (child) or `b.iIbrId` (parent).

As for your existing subquery, there is no need to repeat the `mpm_icabinreq_ibr` table in your subquery. In fact, by doing so (and absent any further constraints on that table reference) I expect that your were seeing many duplicate names in the result, causing you to resort to `DISTINCT`.

Side note: Very often the use of `DISTINCT`, without knowing why, is a sign of an under-constrained query that needs a much closer look. Only use DISTINCT when you ***really*** understand why you need it. An example of a proper might be a customer who buys multiple products and sometimes buys the same product more than once. In that case, querying on distinct product (or writing a query that groups by product) would consolidate the duplicates.

Back to your query, I think that what you want is a select list item something like:

```
SELECT ...
    (
        SELECT
            STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),sCdmName), ', ')
                WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sCdmName)
        FROM mpm_icabinreq_cardmark_rcm
        INNER JOIN mpm_cardmark_cdm ON iRcmCdmId = iCdmId
        WHERE iRcmIbrId = a.iIbrId  -- or perhaps b.iIbrId
    ) AS CardMarks
FROM mpm_icabinreq_ibr a
...
```

For row of your main query result, this will find and aggregate all of the `sCdmName` values matching the `mpm_icabinreq_ibr` record, using `a.iIbrId` and `mpm_icabinreq_cardmark_rcm` as a path to do the lookup.

An alternate syntax that helps unclutter your select list is to move the above subquery into a `CROSS APPLY` after your other joins, resulting in a query like:

```
SELECT ..., CM.CardMarks
FROM mpm_icabinreq_ibr a
...
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),sCdmName), ', ')
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sCdmName) AS CardMarks
    FROM mpm_icabinreq_cardmark_rcm
    INNER JOIN mpm_cardmark_cdm ON iRcmCdmId = iCdmId
    WHERE iRcmIbrId = a.iIbrId  -- or perhaps b.iIbrId
) AS CM
...
```

Comment: Very helpful? I used the first example you gave, the select list, and it worked exactly as I needed. The main issue was, as you noted, the double reference to a table, mpm_icabinreq_ibr. I will try the CROSS APPLY when I get time. THANKS!!!